# C# .NET 3.5 - Performing list like operations on members of a list

Tags: c#, list

I have a field object and I create a list of fields:

```
class Field {

string objectName;
string objectType;
string fieldName;
string fieldValue;

//constructor...

}



List<Field> fieldList = new List<Field>();
```

Suppose I wanted to query this list to return a collection of distinct object names (to then be inserted into a checkedlistbox. How would I go about doing that?

I imagine some LINQ magic can manage this?

Comment: Download LINQpad, http://www.linqpad.net/. it's an easy way to learn LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression should return a List of distinct object names from the list as defined.  I converted it to a list since the docs for the CheckedListBox DataSource property indicated that it needs to implement IList or IListSource, not merely IEnumerable.

```
((ListControl)cbListBox).DataSource = fieldList.Select( f => f.objectName )
                                               .Distinct()
                                               .ToList() );
```

If accessing the checkedListBox as a ListControl doesn't give access to the DataSource (sometimes the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx) lie), you could try:

```
cbListBox.Items.AddRange( fieldList.Select( f => f.objectName )
                                   .Distinct()
                                   .ToArray() );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = from Field f in fileldList select f.objectName;

chkBoxList.DataSource = q.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of these work

Using var

1) var fieldNameCollection = from f in fieldList select f.FieldName;
2) Lambda syntax
var fieldNameCollection = fieldList.Select(f => f.FieldName);

Alternately, instead of using var, you can also use 
IEnumerable fieldNameCollection = fieldList.Select(f => f.FieldName);